# Axon framework with Atomikos? How it's work?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, axon, atomikos

I have a question, I have to use Atomikos with Axon framework, in Spring-Boot (without Axon Server). I am using Oracle DB, and I am using multiple threads (10) to send a lot of commands, and before that I am configuring an JtaTransactionManager for myself, but in some threads I get this kind of exception: javax.transaction.xa.XAException, raised -6 or -4 or -3 or ORA-02056: 2PC: k2lcom: bad two-phase command number rdonly from coord:. As I debugged I saw that the CommandGateWay is using JtaTransactionManager too. Is it right? When is this opening a transaction? Is that  possible that my JtaTransactionManager and Axon's is in conflict?
Did anybody had this kind of exceptions?

Sample code:

```
@Service
public class CreateEntitiesServiceImpl extends FutureCompleter implements CreateEntitiesService {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerHelper.getDeveloperLogger(CreateEntitiesServiceImpl.class);
    private final CommandGateway commandGateway;
    private final ExecutionUtil executionUtil;
    private final MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

    public CreateEntitiesServiceImpl(CommandGateway commandGateway, ExecutionUtil executionUtil, MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository) {
        this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
        this.executionUtil = executionUtil;
        this.myEntityRepository = myEntityRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(Message message) {
        logger.info("Entity addition started!");
        generateEntities();
        logger.info("Entity addition finished!");
    }

    private void generateEntities() {
        ExecutorService executorService = executionUtil.createExecutor(10, "createEntities");

        List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        CreateEntitiesService proxy = applicationContext.getBean(CreateEntitiesServiceImpl.class);

        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> processingFutures = list.stream().map(
                e -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(proxy::createEntity, executorService).whenComplete((x, y) -> executorService.shutdown()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        processingFutures.stream().map(this::getVoidFuture).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createEntity() {
        try {
            MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
            myEntity.setEntityStringProperty("string");
            myEntity.setEntityTimestampProperty(LocalDateTime.now());

            MyEntity savedEntity = myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
            CreateAggregateCommand command = new CreateAggregateCommand(savedEntity.getEntityId(), savedEntity.getEntityStringProperty(),
                    savedEntity.getEntityTimestampProperty());
            commandGateway.send(command);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CreateEntitiesException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully comprehend what you're asking to be honest.

The title states Axon with Atomikos, whilst I don't feel this point ever comes back in the description.

What you are asking in the question description is whether it's correct that the `CommandGateway` uses a transaction manager.

On that matter I can be clear though: yes it does.
Sending a command will very likely end you up within an aggregate instance. As you'd want to guard the consistency boundary within this instance **and** ensure the events which are published get stored, it's sensible to start the transaction as soon as the command is being handled.

By the way, small note: it's the `CommandBus` which uses the `TransactionManager`. Conceptually that doesn't change my description thus far though.

Concluding, I am not entirely sure whether this will help you out, as your question is not completely clear to me. I hope a rewrite of your post will clarify more of what you are actually after.